# What's the difference between attribute and key in dynamodb query

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

Say I have "name" as my primary key and "timestamp" as my sortkey. I realised I can do a query using both Attr("timestamp") and Key("timestamp").

I can also do a table scan using filterexpression(Attr("account").eq("john"))  aswell as a query uding keyconditionexpression=Key("account").eq("john") which give me the same outcome.

So I have two questions. In general, If I have the same conditions does it make a difference if I use scan or query? Whats the significance of having a sort key different to any other numerical attribute when im making a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both a `Scan` with a `FilterExpression` and a `Query` with `KeyConditionExpression` may return the same results, there is a big difference in the way this is done, its performance, and the cost to you. In your case, it is strongly preferrable to use a `Query`, not a `Scan`. Let me explain:

A `Scan` always scans the entire table. It may filter out things according to `FilterExpression`, but DynamoDB still needs to read **all** the items in table, and you will pay for these reads. Doing a scan with a very selective `FilterExpression` (which only returns a small subset of the table) is almost always a bad idea. It will be very slow and cost you a lot, relative to the amount of data you are trying to read.

On the other hand, `Query` can **efficiently** skip directly to the partition you asked for (the `KeyConditionExpression` can only specify a single partition key), and inside this partition, read *only* the sort-key range which you specified in `KeyConditionExpression`. The time it takes to do that, and the cost to you, will only be proportional to the number of items you actually read - even if those are only a small subset of the entire table.

`Query` can do this efficiently because of the way DynamoDB partition keys and sort keys work: The partition key is also called a "hash key" because it allows DynamoDB to find the specific partition efficiently, as in a hash table, without scanning the entire table. Then, *inside* one partition, items are sorted by the sort key, so to find a contiguous range of sort keys (as `KeyConditionExpression` allows to specify), DynamoDB does not need to scan all the items in the partition - it can find the requested range efficiently in O(logN).

Comment: Is there a differencw between making a query with condition on the sort key and the condition on just any numerical attribute?

Comment: Yes! When the condition is on the sort key, DynamoDB can implement it efficiently - bring just the requested items without having to read them all first. When the condition is on a non-key attribute, DynamoDB needs to read the entire partition and filter out non-matching items. You also pay for reading all these items you don't need. To make the difference in performance and cost more obvious, there are two separate expressions - KeyConditionExpression (cheap, only on key) and FilterExpression (can get expensive, on any attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Scan operation is very expensive as it requires to read the entire table. In addition, scan operation is a sure way to him DynamoDB's 1MB limit of the amount of data it can retrieve, so you will likely end up having to do multiple scans and using `NextToken` to continue scanning your table. It is not recommended to use scan in most cases.

[Here](https://www.dynamodbguide.com/scans/) you can find more about scan operation.

A key attribute in DynamoDB can be a subject to conditions in query while non-key attribute can't. Also, DynamoDB supports only `=` (equal) condition on primary key attributes.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/) you will find more on how to choose the right partition key.

Comment: "A key attribute in DynamoDB can be a subject to conditions in query while non-key attribute can't." Could you explain the statement?